# How to write the path of a folder with space in its name?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory, paths

I can't figure out how to write the path of a folder that includes spaces in its name (in Terminal).

I tried:

```
cd /path/path/path/"A Folder"/file

cd /path/path/path/'A Folder/file

cd /path/path/path/A_Folder/file
```

but they all return the error through the terminal:

```
[command]: cannot access '/path/path/path/A Folder/file' No such a file or directory
```

I can still access it through steps like so:

```
cd /home
cd user
cd Desktop
cd "Bash Programming"
bash Example
```

Comment: Please post the **exact** command you're using - not a generic `/path/path/A Folder`. Since the error message includes the full path (with space) it's unlikely to be an issue with the space - more likely you are making an error in the path itself.

Comment: The first one (`cd /path/path/path/"A Folder"/file`) should work.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can enclose the whole path by double-quotes ("), single-quote (') or escape the space character using a backslash (\) :

```
cd "/path/path/path/A Folder/file"
cd '/path/path/path/A Folder/file'
cd /path/path/path/A\ Folder/file
```

Comment: @Shady330 you don't need to enclose the whole path in quotes (though that is neater), your first example should have worked: `cd /path/to/"A folder"`.

Comment: I always just escape...most ergonomic option

Answer (score 10):

Either quote the entire name:

```
cd "/path/path/path/A Folder/file"
```

or escape just the strange characters (space, in this case) using a backslash.

```
cd /path/path/path/A\ Folder/file
```

Another thing to try, is using tab completion:

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/Bas
```

Then press the TAB key, this should complete it to:

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/Bash\ Programming/
```

Then you can type the rest of the path.

Comment: When I try using the tab completion, it just stops before the 'space' and doesn't auto-complete further. Is there some setting in the .bashrc that enables this feature?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
cd Bash\ Programming
```

Or

```
/path/path/path/A\ Folder/file
```

Answer (score 5):

either put all or partial path in single or double quote or escape space with backslash.
Eg:

```
cd /path\ to\ folder  
cd '/path to folder'
```