# Wine is used for installing EXE files. Then why am I getting this error?

Tags: software-installation, wine

Wine is used for installing EXE files. Then why am I getting the following error?

```
$ cd /home/user/Hardware
$ wine LED Player.exe
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeSpinLock stub: 0x54d5f0
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeEvent stub: 0x54d598 0 1
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeSpinLock stub: 0x54d51c
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeEvent stub: 0x54d524 0 1
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeResetEvent (0x54d598): stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfAcquireSpinLock (0x54d51c) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfReleaseSpinLock (0x54d51c 0) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeResetEvent (0x54d524): stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfAcquireSpinLock (0x54d51c) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfReleaseSpinLock (0x54d51c 0) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfAcquireSpinLock (0x54d51c) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfReleaseSpinLock (0x54d51c 0) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeSpinLock stub: 0x1135a0
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeSpinLock stub: 0x1135b0
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeTimerEx stub: 0x1135e0 0
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeDpc stub
fixme:ntoskrnl:KeInitializeSpinLock stub: 0x113628
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfAcquireSpinLock (0x1135b0) stub!
fixme:ntoskrnl:__regs_KfReleaseSpinLock (0x1135b0 0) stub!
wine: Call from 0x7b83aace to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.KeSetTimerEx, aborting
wine: Unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.KeSetTimerEx called at address 0x7b83aace (thread 0031), starting debugger...
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\LED.exe"
*
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: Its QL LED Player.exe

Comment: I recommend expanding this question to explain where you obtained the software and precisely what steps you have attempted so far to install it--especially the steps that produced that error message. (You can [edit] your post to give this information.)

Comment: @vivekpal mv "QL LED Player.exe" QLLEDPlayer.exe

Comment: @vivekpal the command would be wine "~/Downloads/QL LED Player.exe" for example

Comment: Lets also reanalyze what Wine is.  Wine is an **emulation layer**.  It does not work with all Windows programs, nor is it a drop in replacement for Windows, nor can we easily assist you without detailed information.  Also, use quotes around program names/paths that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @AUmarMukthar, but your problem is a different one: You have a space in the name of your EXE, so you have to enclose it in quotes.

This is the reason for the following error message:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\LED.exe"
```

Comment: @vivek pal Have a look at this. How to write the path of a folder with space in its name? http://askubuntu.com/questions/530578/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-folder-with-space-in-its-name

Answer (score 6):

Not every piece of windows software is supported by wine.
To know the list of software supported by wine follow this [link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) and check the software you wish to install.

Comment: Wine is a compatibility layer. **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator.

Comment: Okay i Agree ;-)

Comment: There then have an upvote ;-)